# Error loading CMSMS website

Tags: php, content-management-system

I just uploaded a CMSMS website, but cannot view the website. Am getting the error:

> Warning:
> require(/home/inkbran1/public_html/century21nigeria/lib/smarty/Smarty.class.php)
> [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
> in /home/inkbran1/public_html/century21nigeria/include.php on line 153
>
> Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required
> '/home/inkbran1/public_html/century21nigeria/lib/smarty/Smarty.class.php'
> (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in
> /home/inkbran1/public_html/century21nigeria/include.php on line 153

Please, what can i do? I am a PHP dummy.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the file Smarty.class.php is in the directory listed in the error message.

Comment: I thought as much myself, but how and where do i find the Smarty.class.php file?

Comment: I'm guessing you don't have Smarty installed. A quick google search for the file pointed me to http://www.smarty.net/quick_install .